# Visual Studio Installer Projects product name diacritics

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Installer projects extension to create an installer for my app.

Works OK, but the problem is that the product name contains "š" character in it and the font used in the msi installer obviously doesn't support that character:

[image]

Anything I can do about that?

Some background info:
I initially developed the app in VS 2015 which had a free Install Shield Limited edition. Or maybe it was even VS2013, don't really remember... However, now I need to make some changes in the app. There was no problem with such a name in Install Shield back then. So I tried to open the project in VS 2022, but obviously Install shield's no longer an option. This is where VS Installer project comes in, but there's the problem with the diacritics...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an encoding issue. Try searching in the VS project properties for an option to set the encoding to Unicode. I don't use the VS projects that much, so I don't know if you have the option to change it not, but it might be there.

Also, if you are looking for a better free MSI packaging tool, try the [Advanced Installer extension for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/publishers/caphyon). There is one for each version of VS.

*Disclaimer. I work on the team building Advanced Installer.*

Comment: No, there are really just a few options to the VS Installer project. No encoding whatsoever. Anyway, I tried Advanced Installer and have to say I am impressed. You guys are doing a great job.